# Unity: Cannot access variable of C# script from another object

Tags: unity, c#

I have already found similar questions on *stackexchange.com* related to accessing variables from another object. But my question seems to have a slightly different context and the answers from those questions are not working.

I have the following (stripped off) scene comprising the standard FPS character:

```
Scene001
  |
  |--FPSController
       |
       |--FirstPersonCharacter
```

My (stripped off) Assets hierarchy is as follows (folders are enclosed with <> brackets):

```
<Assets>
  |
  |--<Scripts>
  |     |
  |     |--Actions.cs
  |
  |--<Standard Assets>
        |
        |--<Characters>
              |
              |--<FirstPersonCharacter>
                   |
                   |--<Scripts>
                         |
                         |--FirstPersonController.cs
```

Now `FirstPersonController.cs` is attached to `FPSController` by default and `Actions.cs` is attached by me to `FirstPersonCharacter`.

Excerpt from `FirstPersonController.cs` is as follows:

```
...
namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{    
     ...
     public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
     {
          ...
          private void GetCharacter()
          {    
               GameObject _obj = GameObject.Find("FirstPersonCharacter");// ok here
               bool is_acted = _obj.GetComponent<Actions>().is_acted; // error here, please see below
          }
          ...
     }
}
```

Excerpt from `Actions.cs` is as follows:

```
public class Actions: MonoBehaviour {
    ...
    public static bool is_acted;
    ...
}
```

All I want is to access `bool is_acted` variable of `Actions.cs` from `FirstPersonController.cs`.

Error is as follows:

```
Assets/Standard Assets/Characters/FirstPersonCharacter/Scripts/ 
FirstPersonController.cs(63,38):error CS0246: The type or namespace
name `Actions' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

To me this seems to be a problem of namespace or folder location!!?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Updated above**

- Changed *Action* to *Actions*.
- Corrected typo `()`.

Sample project:

https://ufile.io/knmxj

Comment: Where is your Action.cs file located?

Comment: @Sidar Yes. `Action.cs` is attached as a component to `FirstPersonCharacter` and functions from that `Action` class are running properly. Also, there is only one `FirstPersonCharacter` object i.e. under `FPSController` object. Pardon me, I might not have understood you.

Comment: @Draco18s Sorry! That was a typo and I have also change the name `Action.cs` to `Actions.cs`, otherwise it is taking `System.Action` object. I have updated my question. Kindly wait! I am going to upload my sample project to make it clearer.

Comment: @Draco18s Hello! I have uploaded the project. Are you available to see it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This is caused by Unity

**But it's easy to fix.**

The `Standard Assets` folder is compiled *before* all other scripts (this may be a holdover from when Unity officially supported JavaScript / UnityScript files, which had to be compiled at a different time than C# files, so the Standard Assets were compiled before everything else so that both C# and JS user created scripts could reference it).

All you have to do to fix this is change the name of the folder `Standard Assets` to *anything else* (except another one of the magic keyword names, like `Resources`).

Also, you have another error in your code:

```
public static bool is_acted;
...
GetComponent<Actions>().is_acted;
```

Your field is Static and cannot be accessed via an instance object. Either you should be doing `Actions.is_acted` or remove the static modifier.

Comment: Great! It is compiling now! Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: @user62039 Glad I got it working for you. It was something I just had to play with once I had your project, as its a bizarre feature that isn't documented well/at all.